# wampserver not running on windows 8.1

Tags: windows, exception, wamp, windows-8.1, wampserver

I cant start wampserver on my windows 8.1 and I don't know neither the reason causing this problem nor its solution, a message of exception is appearing :"Exception Exception in module wampmanager.exe at 000F15A0 could not execute run action . "

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble running wampserver on Win 8.1, but cannot remember the error message as it was a long time ago. Do you have MS SQL Server installed? the problem i had was caused by a clash between the two, resolved by stopping MS SQL Reporting Service. Sorry I cant be more specific! It was about 2 years ago on my old laptop.